# in an XSL stylesheet that outputs html, can javascript manipulate the DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, html, xslt, dom

right now, i am just trying to append text with javascript.  i have two div columns and i will be placing items into one or the other depending on how many are in each column already, so i will not know which column to put them in and will have to dynamically assign them to a column.  can javascript do this inside an XSL stylesheet?

Comment: Why not to do this with XSLT itself? Please, provide input sample and desired output to get a stylesheet example.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript can only be used after the page has been rendered and the DOM has elements in it able to be edited. If you want to alternate where items in a dynamically sized list are placed, you will have to do that in the script that marks up the document that is rendered using the XSL Stylesheet.